# Neo4j and Java : What is best?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using an old Library(java-rest-binding) to access my Neo4j database and perform some Cyphers..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
```

This library is not longer maintained because of it's initial design(over the  wire database wrapper service and potential network latency).

I mainly do cypher queries to retrieve some node properties and sometimes extracting a Subgraph and visualise it via a JS library(Keylines)

My question is : what is best Alternative?

I have made some reasearchs and I found some ways of doing what I did before but I have trouble to decide

- Using spring neo4j data?
- Neo4j Spring Jdbc Template ?
- Neo4j java driver ?

Do you see a use for the Neo4j Object Graph Mapper(OGM 3)

Thanks